# Random Seed for Tensorflow federated?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, random-seed, tensorflow-federated, federated-learning

I want to get reproducible results with my Tensorflow Federated code. For that I have implemented some seeds (random, numpy and tensorflow), but they aren't affecting Tensorflow Federated. The data processing steps are all reproducible, it has to be in the code snippet below.

I have read that Tensorflow Federated doesn't provide a global seed function and that my only possibility is to save the state. But I don't understand this argumentation. Is anyone aware of a method/function that can help me out or explain to me why I can't use seeds with Tensorflow Federated?

Appreciate every comment :) Thanks for your help.

```
nest_asyncio.apply()

seed_value = 0 
random.seed(seed_value)
np.random.seed(seed_value)
tf.random.set_seed(seed_value)

# designing the clients
client_train_data = collections.OrderedDict()

for i in range(1, num_clients+1): 
    client_name = "Client_{}".format(i)
    size = len(X_train)//num_clients
    start = size * (i-1)
    end = size * i 
    data = collections.OrderedDict((("label", y_train[start:end]),
                                    ("features", X_train[start:end])))
    client_train_data[client_name] = data

train_dataset = tff.simulation.FromTensorSlicesClientData(client_train_data)

def preprocess(dataset): 
    
    def batch_format(element): 
        return collections.OrderedDict(
            x = reshape(element["features"], [-1, 11]), 
            y = reshape(element["label"], [-1, 1]))

    return dataset.repeat(num_epochs).shuffle(shuffle_buffer).batch(
        batch_size).map(batch_format).prefetch(prefetch_buffer)

def make_federated_data(client_data, client_ids): 
    return [
        preprocess(client_data.create_tf_dataset_for_client(x))
        for x in client_ids
    ]

fl_train_data = make_federated_data(train_dataset, train_dataset.client_ids)

def create_keras_model(): 
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(15, input_dim=11, activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(15, activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))
    return model

def model_fl(): 
    keras_model = create_keras_model()
    return tff.learning.from_keras_model(
        keras_model,
        input_spec=fl_train_data[0].element_spec,
        loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(), 
        metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()])

fl_process = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(
    model_fl,
    client_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01), 
    server_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1.00))
# initialize federated averaging
state = fl_process.initialize()
# federated rounds
for round in range(1, num_rounds+1):
    state, metrics = fl_process.next(state, fl_train_data)
    print("Runde {:2d}, metrics={}".format(round, metrics))
```

Comment: It would be helpful to copy/past the exact code, as where non-determinism is coming from could be a variety of places. Check that all layers of the model have deterministic initializers, any `tf.data.Dataset.shuffle()` calls set a seed, `ClientData.datasets()` calls set a seed, etc.

Comment: Thank you, I have posted the code. Aren't the Keras layers deterministic, because of the `tf.random.set_seed(seed_value)`? So, there is no global function for tff?

Comment: I'm not positive the Keras layers pickup a fixed seed from the graph. [`tf.keras.initializers.GlorotUniform`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/initializers/GlorotUniform) for example (the default for Dense layer kernels). It doesn't seem to use the graph global seed set by `tf.random.set_seed`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. If I set the initializer to `tf.keras.initializers.GlorotUniform(seed_value)` the whole FL approach is reproducible. Thanks a lot. But what confuses me is that the deep learning model was reproducible beforehand on central hosted data without setting the initializer and only using `tf.random.set_seed`. Do you know what's the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Just to second the comments above: Generally TFF best practices include using stateless random number generators in controlled ways in order to get reproducibility (eg. using `tf.keras.initializers` with random seeds to control model initialization).

Global random seeds set in eager mode will not guarantee exact reproducibility. This is because any time a `tff.tf_computation` is invoked, TFF effectively enters a unique `tf.Session` (see https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/faq#how_can_i_ensure_randomness_in_tff_matches_my_expectations). This is also why TFF and centralized TF simulations are different: In TFF, there is no expectation that we can control how TF sessions are entered.